# How do you pass an intent from activity to a fragment that is already opened

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is the answer that I got from other topic and applied it to my codes:

From Activity you send data with intent as:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

These are the codes that I applied, it is not working somehow. The fragment is already opened at the start.

```
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        if (tag.equals("Click to show all routes in this point")) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("route1", "Divisoria - San Juan");
            // set Fragmentclass Arguments
            hideShowFragment fragobj = new hideShowFragment();
            fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            Fragment intersectionFragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer2);
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer2, fragobj);
            ft.show(intersectionFragment);
            ft.commit();
    }
}
```

The codes in my onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hide_show, container, false);
    if (!routes.equals(none)) {
        routes = getArguments().getString("route1");
    } else {
        routes = "Food";
    }
    return view;
}
```

What I want to happen is that the fragment will always update to what marker Tag that I click on the map. In other words, pass the string to the fragment (that is opened) and update it.

I do not want to use startActivityForResult because I can't move around the map if I don't use fragments. Is there a way to send result from activity to fragment that is already opened and running? If none, then how can I make the fragment not running from the start (using supportFragmentManager)? I only know is to hide it

Answer (score 1):

If you have running `Fragment` and want to pass some data to it, you should create some way to communicate. For that purposes, you can use [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

First of all create interface inside `Activity` if you want to pass data to `Fragment`:

```
public interface OnInfoClickedListener {
    void onInfoClicked(String info);
}
```

Implement this interface inside `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onInfoClicked(String info) {
    infoTextView.setText(info); 
}
```

Now, inside your `Activity`, create variable to store this interface implementation:

```
private OnInfoClickedListener listener;
```

And when instantiating `Fragment`, save instance of it to variable:

```
InfoFragment fragment = InfoFragment.newInstance();
listener = fragment;
```

And when needed just provide data through this interface:

```
listener.onInfoClicked("Info - " + UUID.randomUUID());
```

Comment: Can you please help me with the codes? If it's okay with you. I really don't understand :/

Comment: @YaZaoRuZakiaga ok, I'll try

Comment: @YaZaoRuZakiaga I've updated my answer, please, take a look.

Comment: I'm getting a red on the ".NewInstance()" it says 'cannot resolve method' when I put it inside 'public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)'

Comment: @YaZaoRuZakiaga, sorry what you want to do?